# Cannot extend RESTAdapter in Ember.js in development environment. In production all fine

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Faced a strange problem tonight. I have the following RESTAdapter settings:

`app/adapters/application.js`:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend ( {
    namespace: 'api'
} );

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

If I build project with `ember build --environment=production` it works flawlessly. But if I build project with just `ember build`, Ember just ignores my definition and namespace becomes empty string (my `ApplicationAdapter` is completely ignored).

Making it `App.ApplicationAdapter` in app/app.js doesn't help either. In production mode everything is again fine.

Is it a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried directly exporting the adapter instead of assigning it first. Also which version of ember-cli are you using?

Comment: @albertjan Yes, I tried. Actually, `var` there is meaningless. EmberCli was 0.2.3.

Comment: Then it looks like a bug to me. You could try removing node_modules and bower_components and re install them but to be honest I don't see how that would make things work in production and not in development.

Comment: @albertjan Yep. The problem is that I only just installed Ember yesterday to try it.

Comment: life is like `npm install` you never know what you're gonna get. :) I'll see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: @albertjan Thanks for help! You can get my repo from [here](https://github.com/ThirisCart/ThirisCartFrontend/blob/master/app/adapters/application.js)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77087/discussion-between-albertjan-and-vladislav-rastrusny).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce what you are seeing. You do however have to add a `Route` for products if you want to get them from store. For debugging purposes you can get the adapter from the container in the console like this:

```
var appAdapter = Frontend.container.__lookup__('adapter:application');
```

and then check the namespace:

```
appAdapter.get('namespace');
```

Which return `"api"` for me.

If you add a `Products` route:

```
// routes/products.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.findAll('product');
  }
});
```

And navigate to `/products` not `/#products` you'll see a failed ajax request to:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/products 404 (Not Found)
```